# How do I apply bullets to a table column in word using VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have applied bullets to a row without difficulty using

```
myDoc.Tables(1).Rows(3).Range.ListFormat.ApplyBulletDefault
```

but when I try something similar with

```
myDoc.Tables(1).Columns(4).Range.ListFormat.ApplyBulletDefault
```

I get the error method or data member not found with "Range" highlighted in vba.

I'm sure I'm missing something straightforward, but any suggestions would be great.

Comment: Columns don't have a `Range`, as IntelliSense would have shown you. To apply bullets you'll need to loop through each cell in the column.

Comment: "you'll need to loop through each cell in the column", Nooooo, that's what I wanted to avoid!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've settled on two lines of code as follows in case this come up for anyone else:

```
myDoc.Tables(1).Columns(4).Select
myDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Range.ListFormat.ApplyBulletDefault
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).